# Confusion in Cup product structure of $S^2\times S^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology

We have the product space $S^2\times S^2$. By cellular cohomology we have $H^2(S^2\times S^2)$ is $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$. Also by the kunneth formula we have $H^2(S^2\times S^2;\mathbb{Z})=H^0(S^2;Z)\otimes H^2(S^2;Z) \oplus H^2(S^2;Z)\otimes H^0(S^2;Z)$. Now what confuses me is that the isomorphism is given by cross product but let $\alpha$ be a generator of $H^2(S^2;Z)$ and let $\beta$ be a generator of $H^0(S^2;Z)$ then both the elements $\alpha \otimes \beta$ and $\beta \otimes \alpha$ under the cross product map map to the same element. I am missing something trivial but can't figure out what.

Comment: Cellular cohomology certainly does *not* tell us that "$S^2 \times S^2$ is $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$".

Comment: @Lee Mosher But doesn't the $S^2\times S^2$ have  a CW structure using product CW structure having 1 0-cell, 2 2-cells, and 1 4-cell. And thus $H^2(S^2\times S^2) = Z\times Z $.

Comment: Could you please point out where I am going wrong in the kunneth formula.

Comment: Also sorry for the typo edited it.

Comment: I think it's a problem with your notations: note that $\beta_1$ (the generator of $H^2(S^2)$ of the first copy) is certainly NOT the same as $\beta_2$ (the generator of the $H^2$ of the second copy), so they should be distinct.

Comment: yes ofcourse I got confused for no reason. Thanks!